# Basic calculus of the adjoint spinor being transformed under parity

Tags: particle-physics, spinors, parity, dirac-matrices

In Modern Particle Physics (p.287) Thompson says that under the parity transformation of the adjoint spinor we have

$$\bar u=u^\dagger\gamma^0\rightarrow^p (\hat Pu)^\dagger\gamma^0= u^\dagger\gamma^{0\dagger}\gamma^0=u^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^0=\bar u\gamma^0$$

Where $\hat P=\gamma^0$ is the parity operator.
But if I were to do this calculus I would let $\hat P$ act on both, but then it would be:

$$\bar u=u^\dagger\gamma^0\rightarrow^p \hat P(u^\dagger\gamma^0)=\hat P(u^\dagger)\gamma^0= \gamma^{0\dagger}u^\dagger\gamma^0=\gamma^{0\dagger}u^\dagger\gamma^0 $$

Is it correct to say $\gamma^{0\dagger}u^\dagger=\bar u$? If so we've arrived to the same result, but if not, where was I mistaken?

Comment: @ Martin, when you writing $u^\dagger\gamma^0\rightarrow^p \hat P(u^\dagger\gamma^0)$ is the mistake. Look carefully parity is a physical transformation that can only act on the spinor, but not on the gamma matrices.

Comment: @mas ok, that makes sense. But on the next step I kind of do that, right? I take the gamma out of the brackets and calculate the action of the parity on the spinor only. Are there any other mistakes?

Comment: @mas, I noticed he rights $(\hat Pu)^\dagger= u^\dagger\gamma^{0\dagger}$, while I say $\hat P(u^\dagger)= \gamma^{0\dagger}u^\dagger$. Is the operator changed by the dagger too?

Comment: @ Martin. If you take $\gamma^{0\dagger}u^\dagger$ as Dirac adjoint $\bar u$, that's not right. Dirac adjoint of a spinor $\psi$ is defined such that $\bar{\psi}\psi$ is a scalar (invariant under Lorentz transformation). You can check $\gamma^{0\dagger}u^\dagger u$ is not Lorentz scalar.

Comment: @ Martin, $(AB)^\dagger=B^\dagger A^\dagger $.

Comment: @mas. Got it, tks.

Comment: @mas Please post as an answer.